# How to handle email parsing and regular mailboxes?

Tags: email, parsing, dns, mx-record

So I've had this issue in the back of my mind and can't seem to find any article or doc on how to do it properly. The idea is simple: I am implementing an email parsing system so that users can post new entries by directly responding to an email prompt. The setup works fine, MX records are pointing to postmark's servers and they get parsed fine.

I am now looking for a way to keep this setup while adding support for generic mailboxes such as contact@, team@, etc. (kinda going about this backwards I'll admit) Is there a way to do so just by altering the DNS records?

So far, the best I came up with would be to move the parsing to a subdomain but that would mean past emails prompts could no longer be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to handle this via DNS. DNS will only allow you to set and handle the domain part of the equation.

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you're after though:

- Use a subdomain for your application (so emails go to app.yourdomain.com for the app and yourdomain.com for the regular addresses).
- Instead of setting your DNS to forward to you apps email processor (postmark) use your existing servers and forward only the messages you want to go to the app to your email processor (postmark etc).
- Same as the above but have the email processor collect from IMAP mailboxes that you setup.
- Have the email processor forward messages that aren't for your app to your existing servers.

Many of these depend on what your processor (postmark) can actually allow you to do. Each have different features, however the best and most universal approach is to just use a subdomain for your applications email.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two options:

1/ You create a catch all address on your main domain. This address will catch the e-mails which are not contact@, team@, ... For this address you just set up a forwarding to the InboundHash address which you get from PostMark (http://developer.postmarkapp.com/developer-process-configure.html). This means you don't work with MX records at all but with a simple email forwarder

2/ You use the sub-domain option as you described above. For the migration of old customers you probably set up email aliases on the main domain and forward them to the sub-domain.

There is also a third option but I might be biased here. I'm working for http://mailparser.io which could also be a solution for this kind of problem. You could create a catch-all on your main domain which forwards everything to your mailparser.io inbox. There you can parse the original from/to and the "last reply" and send it over to your API.